# submit button not posted in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, post

I have a form with two submit buttons. based on the button clicked i've to process the values on the post page. so i set the value for action attribute on the button click.

In firefox, it posts form fields and the submit button. but in chrome it only posts the form fields and not the button.. This is the code i've used:

```
<html>
<script src='jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#one,#two').click(function(){
     $("#myform").attr("action", "index.php");
        $("#myform").submit();
    });


});
</script>
<?php
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";
?>
<form method="POST" name='myform' id='myform'  >
<input name="iint" value="hiox" type="text">
<input name="one" value="hiox" type="submit" id='one'>
<input name="two" value="hiox" type="submit" id='two'>
</form>
</html>
```

On post firefox outputs like this:

```
Array
(
    [iint] => hiox
    [one] => hiox
)
```

And in chrome14 [linux version],

```
Array
(
    [iint] => hiox
)
```

I need to check what button gets clicked. Any help, greatly appreciated. Thanksl!

Comment: why would you use that? especially considering that the action is exactly the same.. just remove the javascript and you will have the expected outcome

Comment: Yeah that will work. But i've another button which should post the value to another page. That is why i didn't set action field blank in the form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try simulating the button click with function `$('#buttonelement').click();` instead of using `submit();`

Ah, and as `click();` is a standard javascript funcion, you maybe you need to use use GetDocumentByID instead of #id jquery selector.

```
$('#ElementClickedThatCallOne').click(function(){
 $("#myform").attr("action", "index.php");
    document.GetDocumentByID('one').click();
});

$('#ElementClickedThatCallTwo').click(function(){
 $("#myform").attr("action", "index.php");
    document.GetDocumentByID('two').click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! but both button clicks will do the same work thats why i joined the two. Also it is an valid method in jquery. It is working if i didn't use jquery for submimitting

Comment: so i really don't get it. You wanted to process something before the button is clicked and the form is submitted? Than just returning true would be enought instead of submitting the form.

Comment: it's because when you click a button, the form is alrealdy being submitted, just returning true in an event click (or on the onsubmit attribute) allow the submission to processede. If you use form.submit instead, you are submitting with no button click and then not passing the button property. On chrome feels like the your form.submit(); was being processed before the function of event onclick return true and in firefox the opposite.

Comment: but i made one change. i've used **this.click()** in the button click event. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as a followup for the comment I added:

then (you have another action also) that's because in post you will only have the button that submits the form.. but you submit it with javascript..

in ff it works because the javascript runs after the submit button (I guess)..

you should consider approaching another solution like: make them input type="button" (and not submit), on click set the value for a hidden input that can be used in php.. the value for that hidden input will always be available, but will change depending on the button you click

your form would become something like

```
<html>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#one,#two').click(function(){
        $("#myform").attr("action", "index.php");
        $("#who_submitted_the_form").attr('value',this.id);
        $("#myform").submit();
    });
});
</script>
<?php
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";
?>
<form method="POST" name='myform' id='myform' >
<input name="iint" value="hiox" type="text"/>
<input name="who_submitted_the_form" id="who_submitted_the_form" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="one" value="hiox" type="button" id="one">
<input name="two" value="hiox" type="button" id="two">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: I liked your tweak. As you said the script runs after submit in FF and in chrome it is opposite. but  **random_user**  already answered so 1  up for you. Thanks!

Comment: @Sekar ok, I am glad you found a solution and thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

This is because the submit button is only included in the form submission traditionally when said submit button is clicked.

since you're not submitting the form via the traditional `input="submit"` button, no value is included.

You can use this method before `form.submit()`. call the submit button with click function. so, it traditionally calls the submit button.

```
document.form name.submit button name.click();
```